# R - Remove all outliers at once

Tags: r, dataframe, boxplot, outliers

I have a data set imported in R where I am trying to remove the outliers. I did it so far that I identified all outlier values with a boxplot and saved them in a variable.

```
outlier_values_2 <- boxplot.stats(myfileswoNA$smart_1_raw)$out  # outlier values.
boxplot(myfileswoNA$smart_1_raw, main="Outlier", boxwex=0.1)

hist(myfileswoNA$smart_1_raw)
summary(myfileswoNA$smart_1_raw)
```

Now I am trying to remove the lines with the identified outliers. I can do this with one certain value:

```
example <- myfileswoNA[myfileswoNA$smart_1_raw!=4294967295,]
```

But what I would like to do is to remove all outliers at once, which are stored in the variable `outlier_values_2`
For example this way is not working:

```
example <- myfileswoNA[myfileswoNA$smart_1_raw!=4294967295,]
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Or does anyone have an idea?

Comment: If all outlier values are stored in `outlier_values_2`, try `myfileswoNA[!myfileswoNA$smart_1_raw %in% outlier_values_2,]`.

Comment: maybe `myfileswoNA <- myfileswoNA[smart_1_raw<max(outlier_values_2 ) & smart_1_raw>min(outlier_values_2 ),]`.

Comment: thanks @LAP your code is working fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @LAP helped me with my problem.
Here is what he suggested:

> If all outlier values are stored in `outlier_values_2`, 
>   try
>   `myfileswoNA[!myfileswoNA$smart_1_raw %in% outlier_values_2,]`